# Paths from mappings of a multiple nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, combinations, graph-algorithm

I have a set of nodes in my graph. Each node consists of two integers that map to another character. This integer taken alongwith some other character again forms a node that maps to some other integer. I have an initial set of N characters given. Using first N-1 characters and using the mapping given I want to calculate all possible ways of arriving to the last integer.

Ex :  The mapping given is

```
 (1,2) goes to 3
 (3,4) goes to 5
 (3,6) goes to 7
 (1,4) goes to 6
```

The characters are 1,3,4,7. So using integers 1,3,6 and forming nodes and using mappings I have to arrive at integer 7.

From above mapping

```
  (1,4)  goes to 6.
  (3,6)  goes to 7.
```

And hence the result required.

This is some sort of traversing through graphs in which nodes are directed

Comment: you might want to search for [functional dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) and try to reduce the problem to one if its algorithms, it seems very close match already

Comment: Do you need to use all of the first N-1 characters, or can you just use some of them?

Comment: @btilly All of them may be used any number of times (0 or more)

Comment: @Dynamite When you say, "Calculate all possible ways" do you mean count them, list them, or create a data structure which can be used to traverse them all?  Be aware that there can exist cycles, which can make the number of possible answers be infinite...

Comment: Printing down the traversal paths is what I require. Cycles may not exist since the mapping will not any pair (a,a) to a. This can be assumed safely